# Google Drive REST API v3 Android - Login Required error

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am using Google Drive v3 API in my Android app like in this tutorial: https://ammar.lanui.online/integrate-google-drive-rest-api-on-android-app-bc4ddbd90820

This is my code to Google login:

```
Scope SCOPE_DRIVE = new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE);

        if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(
                GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this),
                SCOPE_DRIVE)) {
            GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    RC_SIGN_IN,
                    GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this),
                    SCOPE_DRIVE);
        } else {
            readCotnracts();
        }
```

and to create Drive service:

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(SettingsActivity.this);

    GoogleAccountCredential credential =
            GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                    this, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
    credential.setSelectedAccount(account.getAccount());
    com.google.api.services.drive.Drive googleDriveService =
            new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(
                    AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new GsonFactory(),
                    credential)
                    .setApplicationName("My App")
                    .build();


}
```

Unfortunately, every time when I am calling my Drive Service I am getting this error:

```
com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: b.d.c.a.b.d.b: 401 Unauthorized
    {
      "errors": [
        {
          "domain": "global",
          "reason": "required",
          "message": "Login Required",
          "locationType": "header",
          "location": "Authorization"
        }
      ],
      "code": 401,
      "message": "Login Required"
    }
```

I have no idea what is wrong, I have enabled Drive API in Google Console, added OAuth consent and created OAuth Client ID. 
Thanks

Comment: You should take a look at the [Java quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java), it's an introduction in using the APIs and tells you how to set everything up. I also found [this other tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5144-integrating-google-drive-in-android), seems to be a bit more in depth.

Comment: Hi,did you solve this problem?

Comment: EricZhao not yet, but I have to do it this month.